# Tiling with incommensurate triangles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, tiling, euclidean-lattices

Say that two triangles are *incommensurate* if they do not
share an edge length or a vertex angle, and their areas differ.
Suppose you'd like to tile the plane with pairwise incommensurate triangles.
I can think of at least one strategy.

Spiral out from an initial triangle
in the pattern depicted below, with the red extensions chosen
to avoid length/angle/area coincidences with all previously
constructed triangles.

---

[image: Twisted tiling]

          

<sup>The central $\triangle$ is slightly non-equilateral.
All $\triangle$s incommensurate.</sup>

---

It seems clear that this approach could work, although it might not
be straightforward to formalize to guarantee incommensurate triangles.
Which brings me to my question:

> ***Q.***
>   What is a scheme that details a *lattice tiling*—all vertices at
>   points of $\mathbb{Z}^2$—composed of pairwise incommensurate triangles?

This requires a more explicit design that effectively describes the triangle
corner coordinates in a way that makes it evident that no
lengths/angles/areas are duplicated.
Without such a clear description, it is not even immediately evident (to me) that
it is possible.

The same question may be asked for incommensurate simplex tilings
with vertices in $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

---

See also: [Tiling the plane with incongruent isosceles triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/q/221431/6094).

Comment: Do four zigzags (one for each quadrant, (1,0) to (0,1) to (x,0) to (0,y) and so on), where if need be record all lengths involved, and choose the next x and y to leave room for lengths for the other zigzags. (You may need to divide areas or follow pattern 2 discretely, but a zigzag should work.)  Busy packing, I'll let you fill in.  Gerhard "Going Down Under, American Style" Paseman, 2018.07.29.

Comment: @Gerhard, if I understand your description, you have two triangles sharing the edge joining $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, so the triangles don't meet Joseph's definition of incommensurate.

Comment: Right. Neither does Joseph's first method.  However, with an outward triangular spiral, there is still a chance.  Gerhard "Maybe One Guess Will Work" Paseman, 2018.07.29.

Comment: Why does "displacing corners" lead to incommensurate tilings? Based on the picture, it appears that every edge is shared by two triangles, so...

Comment: @VictorProtsak & Gerhard: You are both correct! I will remove that 1st approach. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I had deleted my comment, based on a possible misunderstanding of your diagram, since I had thought at first that the pink triangles were congruent, and the purple, but I see now that they are not. (By same triangle type, I had meant merely congruent). Your picture would be clearer if you used different colors for all non-congruent triangles.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Oh, I see now that my colorings can mislead. Sorry.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Finally fixed the coloring when this was bumped to the front page.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This is a solution for non-commensurate side lengths only. The question also asks for non-commensurate angles, which this example does not provide.

I follow your approach. I start with a triangle with points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and add three incommensurate triangles, which leads to a new large triangle that is congruent to the first one and has points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. We can repeat this process to tile the plane.

The first points are $A(0,0), B(2,0), C(2,1)$ as in the following image.

[image]

We now add three new points $A'(-4,0), B'(2,-14), C'(24,12)$ on the rays. We note:

(1) All new side lengths are strictly larger than the side lengths of the triangle $A,B,C$.

(2) All new side lengths are distinct (exercise).

(3) The new triangle $\Delta C'A'B'$ is congruent to $\Delta ABC$, in fact there is a right angle at $A'$ and the side $A'C'$ is double as large than $A'B'$.

The new arrangement of the four triangles is incommensurate by (1) and (2).

We can now repeat this process. Since (3) holds, we can use the congruency from $\Delta ABC$ to $\Delta A'B'C'$ to get the next larger triangle. By (1), all new lengths are larger than all old lengths and the new lengths are also distinct by (2). Moreover all points lie on $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

We can fill up all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with incommensurate triangles.

Interesting follow up questions:

- Is there a tiling in which the size of the triangles is bounded?
- How fast do the lengths grow?

Comment: I had intended that triangles "do not share ... a vertex angle," whereas yours do share angles...?

Comment: You are right. Sorry.