# To tile the plane with mutually non-congruent rational triangles of equal area

Tags: discrete-geometry, tiling, diophantine-geometry

We add a little to [Tiling the plane with pairwise non-congruent rational triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445606/tiling-the-plane-with-pairwise-non-congruent-rational-triangles)

**Question:** Can the plane be tiled by pair-wise non-congruent rational triangles all of which have same area? If "yes", can such an equal area tiling be achieved with the perimeters of the triangles upper bounded?

Remark 1: For any given possible area A, https://nyjm.albany.edu/j/1998/4-1p.pdf proves that there are indeed infinitely many rational triangles all with area A. But from among triangles for a given A to select a set that tiles the plane might not be possible. If the answer to the question is "no", one could ask if mutually non-congruent rational triangles whose areas are all one of a finite set of values would tile the plane.

2. I couldn't figure out if the theorem(s) proved in [https://web.archive.org/web/20210414080312/https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper14.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20210414080312/https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecarlp/PDF/paper14.pdf) are relevant here.

**Further question:** Can the plane be tiled by pair-wise non-congruent rational triangles all of which have same perimeter?